# ¿Cómo dar por solucionada una pregunta sin respuesta?

Tags: soporte

Pues eso, tengo varias preguntas hechas que han sido solucionadas desde los comentarios, sin hacer una respuesta y no puedo aceptar como solucionado un comentario.

¿Qué debería hacer para dar como solucionada la pregunta? ¿Hacer yo misma la respuesta con el comentario que me han puesto?

Comment: ¿Relacionado o duplicado? http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1454/6635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te recomiendo que le dejes un comentario al usuario pidiéndole que mueva su comentario a una respuesta para que puedas aceptarla.

Si al cabo de un tiempo razonable el usuario no responde o simplemente decide no hacerlo, puedes agregar la respuesta tu mismo para poder aceptarla.

Es más, sería apropiado que la respuesta incluya una nota explicando que la respuesta en realidad proviene del usuario X, y hasta puedes optar por marcar la respuesta como un *wiki de comunidad* para no recibir reputación por la respuesta de otra persona.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, le escribí pidiéndole que lo pusiese en una respuesta, pero no contestó, le volveré a escribir, a ver... Cómo se hace eso de marcar una respuesta como wiki de comunidad?

Comment: Al redactar la respuesta, encontrarás un pequeño checkbox en la esquina abajo a la derecha identificado como *wiki de comunidad* al que le puedes hacer un tick antes de publicar la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, todo aclarado! @sstan